# Challenges Faced by US Expat in Germany: Seeking FATCA-Compliant Investment Solutions

Tags: investing, germany, expatriate

I have been a US expat in Germany since 2005, aiming to establish an investment portfolio here. Regrettably, I've encountered obstacles preventing me from doing so.

As a US citizen living in Germany, I struggle to find a financial institute willing to work with me. Each time I try to create an account, I am excluded from doing so. I have read that this is because of the Foreign Account Tax Compliance Act (FATCA). I have also looked into creating an investment portfolio back in the USA. However, I am also barred from doing this since I no longer hold residency there.

Currently, I am in a tough place, as I have no way to secure my future. Do you know of any financial institutes or similar places that are FACTA-compliant and offer US citizens the opportunity to create investment portfolios? I would appreciate any tips and help in this matter.

Comment: There are US brokerages that allow international users to open accounts (Interactive Brokers for example). If you're a US citizen then you're a US resident for tax purposes, you just need a US address maybe?

Comment: @littleadv Yeah, the US address is the tough part. I've heard first-hand accounts of individuals who lost their assets due to not being in the country for at least six months each year. On the other hand, individuals who had investment accounts before they left the US are okay. Maybe it also had to do with the brokerage that they had.

Comment: *lost their assets due to not being in the country for at least six months each year* - never heard of that, can you elaborate?